# How do we interpret the covariance matrices $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}$ in the Matrix Variate Normal Distribution?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interpretation, covariance-matrix, matrix

Consider [the Matrix Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution). My first question is: how do we interpret the entries $\textbf{X}_{ij}$ of the random matrix $\textbf{X}(n\times p)$? My second question is: how do we interpret the so called covariance matrices $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}$? Finally, my third question is: how do we calculate the matrices $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of the Matrix Normal Distribution, the entries $X_{ij}$ are samples from the Gaussian distribution with mean $M_{ij}$. To fully characterise their variance though, we need two matrices $U$ and $V$ to set the joint distribution of the row and column vectors of the random matrix $X$. These two covariance matrices provide information about how the rows (via $U$) and columns (via $V$) covary with each other, thus capturing the dependencies within the matrix $X$. A higher value in the diagonal elements of $U$ implies greater variance within each row vector, while non-zero off-diagonal elements imply the covariance between different pairs of row vectors. (the analogy holds for $V$ but for columns) To that effect, if the row vectors were independent $U$ would be diagonal. (and similarly, if the column vectors were independent, $V$ would be diagonal)

To aid our understanding: let's start with a simple multivariate normal distribution, i.e. begin with just with a $k$-dimensional mean vector $\overrightarrow{\mu}$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ that is of dimensions $k \times k$. Then let's say we want to generate three rows of $k$ length in one go, i.e. our $X$ has dimensions $3 \times k$. In that case, $V = \Sigma$ and $U = I_{3 \times 3}$, $U$ controlling the covariance between the three rows and $V$ controlling the covariance between columns. Because we want just three independent rows, our covariance $U$ is an identity matrix.

Bringing this now altogether: The entry $X_{ij}$ is sampled independently from a Gaussian distribution with mean $M_{ij}$ and variances $U_{ii}$​ (for the rows) and $V_{jj}$ (for the columns) and covariances $U_{ij}$​ (across the rows) and $V_{ij}$ (across the columns).

Finally about the calculation of $U$ and $V$: They don't have a closed form so we cannot estimate them directly. That said, we can estimate the likelihood associated with any particular pair $U$ and $V$ so we can generate maximum likelihood estimates for them given a sample of matrix $X^1, X^2, \dots, X^n$ to find reasonable estimates. Both Python and R have packages estimating that likelihoood (for example [`scipy.stats.matrix_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.matrix_normal.html) and [`matrixNormal`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixNormal/) respectively). I have also seen the paper: [*An expectation–maximization algorithm for the matrix normal distribution with an application in remote sensing*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X17300477#sec2) by Glanz & Carvalho who use EM exactly based on that principle.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. However there is still one question: how do we calculate the matrices $\textbf{U}$ and $\textbf{V}$? I did not understand why $\textbf{U} = \textbf{I}_{3\times 3}$ and $\textbf{V} = \Sigma$ in the proposed example.

Comment: As far as I understand, the covariance between vectors is a matrix.

Comment: Ooops sorry I forgot the calculation part. I will add commentary tonight.

Comment: Once again, thank you very much. In the particular example that you have proposed, how did you reach the exhibited result?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by this question, I just said we want to generate a random $3 \times k$ matrix $X$.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused when you say "because we want just three independent rows, our covariance $\textbf{U}$ is an identity matrix". As far as I know, when we calculate covariance between random vectors, the result is a covariance matrix. How can you associate a scalar such as $\textbf{U}_{ij}$ to the covariance between the $i$-th row and the $j$-th row? Should not $\textbf{U}_{ij}$ be a covariance matrix? It seems I am missing the interpretation of covariance between random vectors. Could you please elucidate this concept to me?

Comment: "*Should not $U_{ij}$ be a covariance matrix?*" The Kronecker product of $U_{ij}$ with $V$ is a (scaled) covariance matrix. (cause the Kronecker product of a scalar $\alpha$ and a matrix $B$ is just $B$ scaled by $a$). Look for example at this extreme case where $U$ is an identity matrix and $V$ is a scalar:
`library("matrixNormal"); set.seed(3); n = 6; p = 1; U = I(n); V = 2; M = matrix(rep(0,n*p), ncol=p);  A = sapply(1:1000, function(x) matrixNormal::rmatnorm(M=M, U=U, V=V)); 
paste0("Row variance is: ", apply(A,1, var),"." ); print("Row correlation is: ");print(cor(t(A)))` (cont.)

Comment: Our variance per row is fully controlled by $V$ scaling them so is $\approx 2$. Similarly, our rows are uncorrelated with each other because of $U$ is an identity matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The $i$th column of $X$ has a covariance matrix $V_{ii}U$, and the $j$th row of $X$ has a covariance matrix $U_{jj}V$. Hence, you can think of $U$ as the covariance of the columns, and of $V$ as the covariance of the rows, both up to a constant. I would not go any further than this when interpreting them. They are "factors" of the true interpretable matrix $V \otimes U$.

$U$ has a closed form given $V$, and viceversa, so they are estimated iteratively. See https://doi.org/10.1080/00949659908811970

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: +1, I was trying to find that paper, and I remember reading it (long time ago) but couldn't locate it - I thought I was on disco biscuits about the whole thing. (I have since realised that it is also referenced in the relevant Wikipedia article which only adds insult to my (bibliographic) injury).